# How can I keep data of a foreign key when its parent is deleted?

Tags: mysql, database

I am making a database that has:

- `Artist` Table
- `CD` table which references the artist.

I want it to be the case that when the `Artist` is deleted from the database, the `CD` they have made must **not be deleted automatically**, but it should still be possible to delete the `Artist` they have made.

I am a novice MySQL coder, and I presume it's something to do with **ON DELETE CASCADE/RESTRICT/SET NULL** or something like that but not 100% sure, I'm pretty sure it is **NOT ON DELETE CASCADE** though.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the CD records then you'll need to set their foreign key field to the parent (Artist) to NULL, (or to a different Artist record) before you delete the Artist. In MySQL you can get the foreign keys set to NULL automatically using ON DELETE SET NULL.

You should consider whether you really want to do this- it will leave your data in a strange state. Why do you need to delete an Artist but not its corresponding CDs?

Comment: Thank you this has worked, and my database is a recordlabel of artists, and they come and go, and they wish not to have there personal work identified as theirs when they leave.

Answer (score 0):

You should first delete all references to the artist you want to delete, then there should be no problem deleting the artist. You can't delete an object if there are still references to this object.

Comment: Would it be okay to say ON DELETE SET NULL on the foreign key constraint, because i don't need the information about the artist, but i need the ability to delete the artist and still have the CD avaiable.